# Run-time error in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I've immplemented an SQLite database here. The database consists of objects of class Contact. However my app is crashing as soon as it starts. Here's the Logcat and the code.

**Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample, PID: 30065
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {
  com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample / com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample.MainActivity
 }: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error(code 1): ,
 while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontacts(idINTEGER KEYname TEXT)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2198)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error(code 1): ,
 while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontacts(idINTEGER KEYname TEXT)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java: 889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java: 500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java: 588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram. < init > (SQLiteProgram.java: 58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement. < init > (SQLiteStatement.java: 31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java: 1672)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java: 1603)
at com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample.DatabaseHandler.onCreate(DatabaseHandler.java: 28)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java: 252)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java: 164)
at com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample.DatabaseHandler.addContact(DatabaseHandler.java: 40)
at com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java: 21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 5248)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2162)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2257) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 139) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1210) 

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample, PID: 32547
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {
  com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample / com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample.MainActivity
 }: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error(code 1): ,
 while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontacts(idINTEGER KEYname TEXT)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2198)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error(code 1): ,
 while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontacts(idINTEGER KEYname TEXT)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java: 889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java: 500)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    // Inserting Contacts
    //Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addContact(new Contact(1, "one"));
    db.addContact(new Contact(2, "two"));
    db.addContact(new Contact(3, "three"));


    TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    Contact cn;
    cn=db.getContact(2);
    text.setText(cn.name);
}



}
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact
{
public String name;
public int id;

Contact(int id, String name)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
}


}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME="contactsManager";
 private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS="contacts";
 private static final String KEY_ID="id";
 private static final String KEY_NAME="name";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE="CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+KEY_NAME+" TEXT"+")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
 db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_CONTACTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

void addContact(Contact contact)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.name);
    values.put(KEY_ID, contact.id);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

Contact getContact(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

public int updateContact(Contact contact)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.name);


    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.id) });
}


}
```

**activityMain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.sqliteexample.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is simple error with your query that you are doing in your database. add some spaces to keywords not to confuse Sqlite and do so as i shown below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) on how to properly create a database.You are missing spaces after "CREATE TABLE" and TABLE_CONTACTS

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You have missed a **space** after CREATE TABLE statement and I think **comma(,)** after PRIMARY KEY

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT"+")";
```